# client_max_body_size for images in location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to increase max size of attaching images for POSTing in my media directory, but using such instruction i getting 413 Request Entity Too Large

```
location ~* .+/media/.+\.(jpeg|gif|png|jpg) {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        }
```

What is my mistake?

Such instructions as:

```
location ~* .+/media/.+ {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        }
```

and:

```
 location ~* .+\.(jpeg|gif|png|jpg)$ {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        }
```

Don't working too

Comment: it must be increased for the uploading script

Comment: So, if i increase it in uploading script, i have to insert  client_max_body_size in server context of nginx, right? By default it is 1mb...

Comment: if we need a single `location` then we have to copy/`include` the fcgi config there. `location = /upload.php { client_max_body_size 20M; include fcgi_config; }` Otherwise we forced to increase max body size for all scripts in the fcgi `location`.

Comment: You will need to post more of your configuration for specific help, but `server` context, or the `location` that processes the upload URI.